# Updating jquery-ui tooltip during hide animation breaks it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

Whenever you update the content of a jquery-ui tooltip while the hide-animation is running, it'll pop back into visibility and enter some broken state where it is visible forever and unresponsive to events.

Yeah, i know, i know, the lib is dead.
Still, is there any way to get around this bug? I need to update my tooltip in 1 second intervals because it has a timer in it, and I would like to use a fade-out animation somehow.

Demo:
Just move the mouse in and out of the first block a couple of times:

```js
$("#animated").tooltip( {items: "div", content: ""} );
$("#not-animated").tooltip( {items: "div", hide: false, content: ""} );

setInterval( function() {
  $("#animated").tooltip("option", "content", Math.random().toFixed(3));
  $("#not-animated").tooltip("option", "content", Math.random().toFixed(3));
}, 500 );
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="item" id="animated">hiding animated</div>
<div class="item" id="not-animated">hiding not animated</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try updating the `.ui-tooltip-content` element manually.

```js
$(function() {
  function getRandom() {
    return Math.random().toFixed(3);
  }

  function updateContent() {
    $(".ui-tooltip-content", $("#animated").tooltip("widget")).html(getRandom());
    $("#not-animated").tooltip("option", "content", getRandom());
  }

  $("#animated").tooltip({
    items: "div",
    hide: 200,
    content: getRandom
  });
  $("#not-animated").tooltip({
    items: "div",
    hide: false,
    content: getRandom
  });

  var intv = setInterval(updateContent, 500);
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="item" id="animated">hiding animated</div>
<div class="item" id="not-animated">hiding not animated</div>
```

Comment: @Nyuton I did notice that and I was not sure if that was needed as part of the tooltip. A) It's strange that it remains open when being updated during fadeOut B) strange that it doesn't update as it should in this script. Will have to tinker more.